# How to change Image Source while clicking on the ListView in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView in which I have a image and a Text inside a viewcell, What My requirement is to change the image on selected row, I acheived it by,

```
var listView = new MyQuestionView(listData);

        listView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
            listView.ItemsSource = null;

            //Update the IconSource here in listData
            var s = e.SelectedItem as MenuItem;
            s.IconSource = "foo.png";

            listView.ItemsSource = listData; //Updated List
        };
```

But, The screen flickers for a second while updating like this. Is there a proper way for updating a row's element.

**This is the code for my Listview:**

```
public class MyQuestionView : ListView
{
    public MyQuestionView (ObservableCollection<MySelectedQuestions> Qdata)
    {
        ObservableCollection<MySelectedQuestions> data = Qdata;

        ItemsSource = data;
        HasUnevenRows = true;
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
        SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.Default;
        SeparatorColor = Color.FromHex("#4Dffffff");
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

        ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (() => {

            // Create views with bindings for displaying each property.
            Label titleLabel = new Label ();
            titleLabel.FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium,typeof(Label));
            titleLabel.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, "Text");
            Image image = new Image ();
            image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "IconSource");

            return new ViewCell {
                View = new StackLayout {
                    Padding = new Thickness (5),
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                    Children = {
                        image,
                        new StackLayout {
                            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                            Spacing = 0,
                            Children = {
                                titleLabel
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        });

    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does it still work if you do not set the ImageSource to null before changing it?

Comment: @WilliamCorncobDecker Yes I can, updated the code of changing Imagesource..

Answer (score 3):

You could make some animations using Triggers to avoid flicker:

```net
Image image = new Image ();
image.Triggers.Add(new Trigger(typeof(Image)) {
    Property = Image.SourceProperty,
    EnterActions = {
        new FadeTriggerAction() {
            StartsFrom = 1
        }
    },
    ExitActions = {
        new FadeTriggerAction() {
            StartsFrom = 0
        }
    }
});
```

**FadeTriggerAction.cs:**

```net
public class FadeTriggerAction : TriggerAction<VisualElement>
{
    public FadeTriggerAction() {}

    public int StartsFrom { set; get; }

    protected override void Invoke (VisualElement visual)
    {
        visual.Animate("", new Animation( (d)=>{
            var val = StartsFrom == 0 ? d : 1-d;
            visual.Opacity = val;

        }),
            length:1000, // milliseconds
            easing: Easing.Linear);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! But My issue was not with the image, it is the list which flickers..  My question was "Am I updating the ListView properly?" is there any other way to update ListView??

Comment: You shouldn't reassign listData. You should modify existing ObservableCollection and the changes will automatically refresh without flicker. Don't do listView.ItemsSource = listData; multiple times. Do it only once anch change the original list accordingly. Also be sure that your MenuItem implements IOnNotifyPropertyChanged interface (eg. for IconSource property) - without it, the list won't be refreshed.

Comment: If possible can you provide me an example or online source on how to implement ListView withIOnNotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: http://motzcod.es/post/87917979362/pull-to-refresh-for-xamarinforms-ios (middle of the page) and http://www.polouchkine.com/using-an-observablecollection-in-xamarin-forms-labs/

Answer (score 0):

In my listbox I had an image which would toggle when they clicked on it (ticked and unticked). To do this I had the Source of the image bound to a string which specified the resource name. I was also having issues with the listview flashing.

To resolve the issue, I changed the xaml to have the two images (ticked/unticked) overlaying each other, put a binding on the opacity, and alternated the opacity (0/1).

A snippet of the xaml and code is below.

**XAML:**

```
<Image Source="TickboxTicked.png" Opacity="{Binding TickedOpacity}" WidthRequest="40" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CompleteCommand}" CommandParameter=""/>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
<Image Source="TickboxEmpty.png" Opacity="{Binding UntickedOpacity}" WidthRequest="40" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CompleteCommand}" CommandParameter=""/>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public bool Complete { get; set; }
public string TickboxImageSource
{
    get
    {
        return Complete ? "TickboxTicked.png" : "TickboxEmpty.png";
    }
}

public int TickedOpacity
{
    get
    {
        return Complete ? 1 : 0;
    }
}

public int UntickedOpacity
{
    get
    {
        return Complete ? 0 : 1;
    }
}

...
public async void OnCompletePressed(object source)
{
    Complete = !Complete;
    OnPropertyChanged("Complete");
    OnPropertyChanged("TickedOpacity");
    OnPropertyChanged("UntickedOpacity");
}
```