# Xamarin - blinking when i replace image source

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working with xamarin forms and trying to create navigation menu. I need to set new image when i click on cell. I have some blinking when i replace image.

I create image:

```
var image = new Image { Source = "Image.png"; }
```

I add it on my grid

```
    var profileTapRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
                profileTapRecognizer.Tapped += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    ItemClicked(sender as ITaggedCell);
                };

        image.GestureRecognizers.Add(profileTapRecognizer);

    grid.Children.Add(image, i, 0);
```

And in ItemClicked i change source and have blink before new image was set:

```
image.Source = "NewImage.png"
```

I tried

```
image.BatchBegin() 
image.Source = "NewImage.png" 
image.BatchCommit()
```

and this way [How to change Image Source while clicking on the ListView in xamarin.forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790198/how-to-change-image-source-while-clicking-on-the-listview-in-xamarin-forms)

What is the best way to change image?

Answer (score 13):

Not a direct solution, but if you're changing image, why not animate? that would even look good!

First fade out, then replace, then fade in!

```
await image.FadeTo(0, 250);
image.Source = "NewImage.png";
await image.FadeTo(1, 250);
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution - to add two images and change opacity to 0/1

Comment: Thank you very much this is a great idea, having multiple images on top of each other and instead of changing the visibility or the source change the opacity, no flickering whatsoever.  Thanks